# How to log out from admin or front-end only?

Tags: admin

It's a minor inconvenience that when I try to login to front-end as other user I have to open incognito mode because by default I am logged in as admin on the frontend and if I log out it also log me out from the backend.

Is there a way to deal with this issue?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/

Comment: I simply use Private Window/Incognito Mode to test my sites as guests when developing Guest/admin-specific features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing like 'logout from dashboard/backend' or 'logout from front end'. When you log out then certain cookies are cleared from your browser. Log out is for all of the pages (both for front end and back end).

Comment: So what's your practice when you are trying to see the pages as a guest or regular user?

Comment: @shenkwen Simply I use another browser.

Comment: Also another kind of minor inconvenience but thanks for your answer

Comment: You can also use Incognito mode or Private Browsing mode, since that'll come at the site with no cookies set.